# Where to put onclick ... or should I be using .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I am trying to make a rudimentary GUI for a memory game. I am at a loss as to how to get the id of each td to display with onclick. I don't think I am thinking rightly about when things are happening with var cellID. The rest of this works. See comments.

```
function cid(){alert(cellID);}//**<-- I feel like this shouldn't be here.** 

function makeBoard(h,w){
var $tab, $row, $cell;

   $tab = $('<div>')
       .attr('id','game')
       .appendTo('#memorygame');


       for(var i = 0; i < h; i++){
            $row = $('<tr>')
            .appendTo($tab);
            for(var j = 0; j <w; j++){
                 var cellID = ('row'+i+'col'+j)
                 $cell = $('<td onclick="cid()">')//**<-- this isn't working**
                 .attr('id',cellID)
                 .appendTo($row);
            }
         } 
     }
         $(makeBoard);
```

Comment: Can you show html's code ?

Comment: No it shouldn't be there. The javascript is just returning a value (a variable that doesn't even exist in scope I might add), but there is no where to return it to. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to display where when what is clicked?

Comment: My apologies, I should be more clear. I want each cell to alert it's id when clicked. The html just contains <div id='memorygame'></div> in the body. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$cell = $('<td>')
    .attr('id',cellID)
    .click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    })
    .appendTo($row);
```

Or insetad of alert you can use

```
$('#whereyouwanttodisplay').html($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Even if you stick with `alert()`, Maturicz' point still stands – get the ID using `$(this).attr('id')` in the handler.

Comment: Also – if you're only setting that ID so that you can extract the row and column in Javascript later, consider using `.data('row', i)` and `.data('col', j)` instead – you can retrieve these in the handler using `$(this).data('row')` and `$(this).data('col')`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is exactly what was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your using a valid selector in the jquery function.  Try creating the td first then add the attribut like this.      $('').attr('onclick' , 'cid()')